# SharePoint Publishing home page not indexed

Tags: search, crawl

I have a SharePoint 2010 site collection with several webs.

For a given web I have:
Page A is an article page and the home page.
Page B is an article page in the same web.

If I make a change to the content of both pages and perform an incremental crawl I'm only able to search on page B. Page A does not appear to be indexed.

If i swap the pages so B is the home page and A is not then make some changes to both pages only page A is indexed correctly. In short the home page for a web does not appear to be indexed (using incremental crawl) even though changes have been made to it.

Anyone know why this happens?

Edit: It appears that the page is actually visited by the crawler (tested by hooking up fiddler to the crawler), but changes are still not indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in the [SharePoint 2010 April 2012 Cumulative Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2598304) package:

> Issues that this hotfix package fixes:
>
> > - Changes on the Home.aspx page are not crawled through an incremental crawl in SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Don't get confused by the description only mentioning Home.aspx, which relates to Wiki pages. I have installed the update and it sorts out the issues with incremental crawl of welcome pages on publishing sites as well.